# UPDATE, campo com "placeholder query" falha na execução

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, placeholder

Segue o código:

```
$campo = $_POST['campo'];
        $valor = $_POST['valor'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tabela");
        mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");
        $consulta = $mysqli -> prepare("UPDATE tabela SET ? = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        $consulta -> bind_param("sss",$campo,$valor,$id); <-------
        $consulta -> execute();
```

Erro ocorre na linha com a flechinha, erro por escrito:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Erro deve estar ocorrendo devido ao CAMPO está com *placeholder*(?), pois eu substitui pelo Campo por escrito e funcionou, ou seja, a *query* não é feita com o campo com *placeholder*.

Só que o campo do meu código vai depender de qual campo o cliente escolheu para editar na tabela.

A não ser que eu faça 10 *queries* (são 10 campos), e determino cada campo no lugar do *placeholder*.

Primeiro, isso ocorre mesmo? E se sim, o que posso fazer como boa prática, para este caso?

Comment: Ah, sim, todos os POSTS são recebidos com sucesso, o erro mesmo, que para mim é novo, é saber que não posso usar placeholder(caracterisca do prepared statements) no campo(SET = ?(campo))..
Como disse, eu substitui o placeholder(?) pelo nome do campo(SET = Rua(campo)) e funcionou, mas para meu caso isso não serviria, já que o Campo podem ser 10, isso depende do que o cliente escolher para dar o update!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é consistente com o funcionamento das consultas preparadas. Elas podem ter *placeholders* para valores mas não para toda a sintaxe da consulta, caso contrário não faria sentido usar um recurso que justamente tenta cachear a *query* (portanto ela precisa ser conhecida por completo) e dar segurança (portanto ela não pode permitir que qualquer informação seja colocada na sintaxe da consulta).

Eu já havia alertado em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47440/101) para o fato de que o `preprared()` não é essa maravilha toda, embora eu não disse que não deveria usá-lo, afinal ele tem utilidade. Aparentemente você gostou mais da resposta que não questiona o uso de um recurso que não é panacéia.

Não estou dizendo para abandonar o seu uso, apenas digo que você terá que criar um consulta preparada para cada campo que pode ser utilizada. Obviamente que em consultas tão heterogêneas a vantagem da performance será menos aproveitada.

Se isso for muito trabalhoso você até poderá optar pela *query* normal para fazer o que deseja de forma "mais fácil". Mas se não souber bem o que está fazendo para garantir que esta flexibilidade não seja explorada você brincará com o perigo.

O que você pode fazer para facilitar o uso da consulta preparada é montar o texto da *query* na mão e usar *placeholder* apenas onde ele pode ser usado. É um misto entre as duas técnicas. Se a lista de campos que podem ser usados está só no seu código no servidor e não vem de fora você terá segurança que não haverá injeção de código. Algo assim:

```
$consulta = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tabela SET $campo = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$consulta->bind_param("ss", $valor, $id);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/SimpleQuery.php).

Mas não pegue o campo de `$_POST['campo']`, caso contrário estará se arriscando, monte um *array* no código e selecione uma opção de acordo com uma seleção que vem de fora. Dar flexibilidade demais para o usuário compromete a segurança.

Comment: Havia pensando nessa do cachear e da questão de segurança! Agora entendi realmente o que aconteceu, e apliquei essa técnica mista, e funcionou. 
Não havia visto sua resposta no outro tópico e se mostrou mais completa e detalhada, então eu revi o meu conceito, parabéns pelas explicações, estão em nível e bem detalhadas, agradeço pelo conhecimento!