# Entity Framework ou Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, entity-framework

**Quando usar Entity Framework exemplo:**

```
var registros = db.Tabela.AsQueryable();
registros = registros.Where(r =>
(intTipo == 0 || r.IdTipo == intTipo) &&
r.IdArea == intIdArea &&
r.DataInicio <= DateTime.Now &&
(r.DataFim == null || r.DataFim >= DateTime.Now) &&
r.Aprovado == true &&
r.Homologado == true &&
r.Excluido == false);
```

Quando usar procedure:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Anderson
-- Create date: 22/01/2015
-- Description: Teste
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE TestedePerformace 
    @intTipo int = 0, 
    @intIdArea int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABELA  R
    WHERE ( R.INTTIPO = @intTipo OR R.INTTIPO = 0 )
    AND r.IdArea == @intIdArea 
    AND ( r.DataInicio <= DateTime.Now or r.DataInicio = null)
    AND r.Aprovado = 1
    AND r.homologado = 1
    AND r.excluido = 0
END
GO
```

Pelo exemplos eu posso chamar o EF consumindo a procedure e posso fazer lambda, minha duvida, num cenario que preciso de somente consulta rapida os dois são a mesma coisa? Se sim qual seria o ganho de ter uma procedure pre-compilada?

Estou usando [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) e coloquei o mesmo **SELECT** da procedure e validei que bem mais rapido do que usar o EF para consultas. Inclusive no curso que fiz com Eduardo Pires ele recomenda o uso de [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) para consultas e DELETE INSERT UPDATE usar EF com Lambda.

Uma tabela com 800 registro

```
//Begin timing
  stopWatch.Start();


  var listaEF     = autorizacaoRepository.All();
  var listaDapper = autorizacaoRepositoryReader.All();
  //Stop timing
  stopWatch.Stop();

            // Write result 
            //Dapper TotalSeconds = 0.0016825
            //EF     TotalSeconds = 3.928575
            //var time = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Minha duvida é uso de Procedure com EF é mesmo coisa que fazer EF com lambda?
Existe algum ganho?

Outra o uso de Dapper simulando o conteudo da Procedure tem algum ganho?

Acho que coloquei os exemplo e só quero contribuir com comunidade, porque sei que exite muitas pessoas que defendem somente um e outro, mas quando sabemos melhor usar todos em cada situação todos ganham.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Na pergunta original havia exatamente essa parte no conteúdo. Por questões históricas, estou mantendo este pedaço da pergunta antiga porque é pertinente para o resto.

## Gostaria de saber se realmente as Stored Procedures são melhores em desempenho do que EF. Poderiam me ajudar?

São. O Dapper, outro Framework de mapeamento objeto-relacional, coloca isso num arquivo de apresentação deles no Github, [que pode ser lido aqui](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Readme.md#performance).

Simplesmente comparar a execução de uma Stored Procedure com um procedimento inteiro de um ORM não é algo muito justo. Para a execução de uma Stored Procedure dentro de um sistema, é preciso instanciar alguns objetos que farão a comunicação com o banco, enviar o comando, e algumas vezes recolher o resultado da execução, que pode ser um código de status ou resultados em forma de tabelas. O ORM, por sua vez, resolve uma porção de procedimentos que você teria que fazer manualmente. Obviamente ele não será tão rápido.

Agora, eliminar um ORM apenas por desempenho é preciosismo. Para a grande maioria dos sistemas, a diferença de performance nem é percebida, sobretudo se você está desenvolvendo aplicativos com as versões mais recentes dos Frameworks.

## Minha duvida é uso de Procedure com EF é mesmo coisa que fazer EF com lambda? Existe algum ganho?

Utilizar expressões de predicado (vulgo lambda, como vocês gostam de dizer) faz o Entity Framework montar uma query textual de acordo com o provedor em que está conectado. Normalmente é no Microsoft SQL Server, mas pode ser qualquer outro (Oracle, MySQL, etc.).

O ganho é em legibilidade de código. Fica muito mais interessante para o programador montar uma lógica em nível de código que ficar tendo que abstrair consultas dependentes de tecnologia pela questão do desempenho.

## Outra: o uso de Dapper simulando o conteúdo da Procedure tem algum ganho?

O ganho é ele traduzir os resultados para um objeto rapidamente, aspecto este que vejo como o grande diferencial do Dapper. Na questão da execução, ele é idêntico à execução pura do objeto nativo de conexão e comandos.

Answer (score 5):

### Gostaria de saber se realmente as Stored Procedures são melhores em desempenho do que EF.

**Versão Curta**: YMMV, *Your mileage may vary* (ou, sua experiência pode ser diferente da minha.)

**Versão Longa:** Performance, em um banco de dados, depende de uma miríade de fatores. Nesta resposta eu irei mencionar minha experiência pessoal.

Eu tenho o seguinte ambiente-alvo:

- Oracle 12c
- Dapper
- Camada Micro-ORM desenvolvida internamente

Durante nossos testes de performance, avaliamos a possibilidade de criação de pacotes para operações de CRUD e consulta, o uso de queries parametrizadas e *statements* diretos. Assuma, para os devidos fins, que possuímos um DBA competente e que o banco de dados está corretamente otimizado e a equipe de desenvolvimento está seguindo as recomendações de *schema* (indexação, tipos de campos, etc).

Estes foram os nossos resultados, para 1 milhão de chamadas, em uma tabela contendo 780.000 registros, com *pipeline* ajustado para 20 chamadas em paralelo. Ignore o aspecto negativo de segurança apresentado pela concatenação de parâmetros no terceito método - ele foi utilizado para mensuração de performance apenas:

**Seek**

```
Método               Chamada
[pkg].[proc]         exec smp.fetch_usr
Parametrized Query   SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE ID = :parm
Direct Statement     "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE ID = " + parm

Método               Média
[pkg].[proc]         ~18 s.
Parametrized Query   ~17 s.
Direct Statement     ~218 s.
```

A performance para *statements* diretos era esperada, já que os planos de execução são recompilados a cada chamada. A surpresa foi constatar que *queries* parametrizadas eram mais rápidas.

Após análise, a razão é óbvia: enquanto que tanto SPs quanto PQs sofrem *caching* e reutilização dos planos de execução, PQs não envolvem pacotes, eliminando assim uma camada extra de avaliação de permissões por escopo.

A performance para operações de alteração foi similar:

**Update**

```
Método               Chamada
[pkg].[proc]         exec smp.upd_usr 
Parametrized Query   UPDATE tbl_user SET desc = :parm2 WHERE ID = :parm1
Direct Statement     "UPDATE tbl_user SET desc ='"+ parm2 + "' WHERE ID = "+ parm1

Método               Média
[pkg].[proc]         ~21 s.
Parametrized Query   ~23 s.
Direct Statement     ~317 s.
```

De novo, PQs e SPs se comportaram de maneira análoga, utilizando planos de execução pré-compilados e cacheados pelo *DBMS*.

Como consequência da análise acima, foi decidida pelo time de desenvolvimento a adoção de *queries* parametrizadas como método de interface entre nosso ORM e o banco de dados.

Finalmente, respondendo sua pergunta: minha experiência com *Entity Framework* é limitada. Entretanto, [de acordo com o conteúdo desta resposta do SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201403/force-entity-framework-to-use-sql-parameterization-for-better-sql-proc-cache-reu), EF suporta o uso de PQs a partir da versão 6. Você pode assim se beneficiar do modelo do EF e da performance de PQs.