# SQL no código ou no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, estilo-de-codificação, stored-procedures

Estou com uma grande dúvida em relação onde devo colocar a minha *query* SQL, se no código ou no *banco*.

Atualmente tenho uma *procedure* que é montada de acordo com os parâmetros que tenho, ou seja, `filtros`.

## Procedure

```
@escopoVerificacao varchar(MAX) = NULL
SET @sql = 'SELECT OrdemOrigem, OrdemTipo, IDCal, FROM  NormasCALClientes AS NCC' 
IF @escopoVerificacao IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' inner join VerificacoesClientes on VerificacoesClientes.IDCalCliente = NCC.IDCalCliente 
                                    AND VerificacoesClientes.IDCal = NCC.IDCal ' END exec(SQL)
```

## No C#.

```
  StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("SELECT OrdemOrigem, OrdemTipo, IDCal, FROM  NormasCALClientes AS NCC");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(escopoVerificacao.Text))
        query.Append("inner join VerificacoesClientes on VerificacoesClientes.IDCalCliente = NCC.IDCalCliente 
AND VerificacoesClientes.IDCal = NCC.IDCal");`
```

## Dúvidas:

- É boa pratica trafegar o texto criado no C# para o banco
  como no 2º exemplo? Já ouvi falar que não seria uma boa pratica.
- Em questões de Manutenibilidade e legibilidade, qual dos exemplos é
  melhor?
- O exemplo 1 poderia afetar o desempenho do banco, pelo fato de executar os `ifs`?
- Qual usar?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Faça um teste com os dois e chegue à conclusão por você mesmo nas condições do que você vai usar. O código tem menos influência que a base de dados onde só você tem acesso. E tenha em mente que no futuro com uma base um pouco diferente da atual isso **pode** mudar.

Talvez você faça um teste e não consiga perceber a diferença. Aí você saberá que a performance não importa e deve optar por fazer o que for mais fácil de dar manutenção. Preocupações com performance raramente fazem sentido se você não estiver vendo um grande problema. E se o problema existir, o jeito é verificar por conta própria se outra maneira ajuda de forma significativa.

É possível que o primeiro código execute ligeiramente mais rápido por alguma otimização do SQL Server mas eu não contaria com uma grande diferença, pelo menos não na maioria dos casos.

Há controvérsias de qual é mais legível e fácil de manutenção. Eu acho que no código da aplicação sempre é mais legível mas há pessoas que dizem o contrário. Qual você acha que você vai se dar melhor para mexer no futuro? Existe alguma razão para colocar no banco de dados?

Mesmo quem prefere por no banco de dados admite que não é tão simples dar manutenção em código no banco de dados. Então é mais um motivo para só escolher esta opção se realmente obtiver um ganho considerável, o que raramente é o caso.

Veja mais no [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/158534/389) e no [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2450/41). Note que se você é programador provavelmente vai querer colocar a lógica na aplicação e se você é DBA tentará a todo custo colocar a lógica no banco de dados :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então a conclusão varia de usuário para usuário?
Na minha opinião no código também é mais fácil de manutenção.
Respondendo as perguntas a primeira acho que seria no código, e a 2º não teria razão para deixa-lá no banco.

Comment: Varia de acordo com a base de dados. O que pode ser bom hoje pode não ser amanhã (claro que esse amanhã não é amanhã de verdade). Mas pode continuar igual também. Depende do padrão de dados contido nele. Não é aleatório, dependendo do padrão você terá estatísticas diferentes e o otimizador poderá trabalhar diferentemente. Eu normalmente não coloco no banco de dados até que eu prove que eu vou ter vantagem **significativa**. Colocar o código no DB normalmente traz vantagem mas na maioria dos casos é tão pouca que não vale o trabalho de ter que dar manutenção nele.

Comment: Estou achando mais fácil dá manutenção nas Querys pelo código @bigown, mais em relação a desempenho estou sentindo diferença nenhuma.

Comment: Em quase todos os casos a diferença é quase zero mesmo. Não é zero de fato mas mas zero é um número absoluto demais :) Se você não está notando diferença é o que importa. Velocidade só para dizer que usou o mais rápido nunca é vantagem. Velocidade porque torna a experiência de uso melhor, consegue dar uma vantagem real perceptível é vantagem.

Answer (score 9):

## Conclusão:

> Dê preferência a escrever as queries no lado do aplicativo em vez de escrever em stored procedures.

## Por que:

A seguir, alguns fatores que pendem para o lado de escrever queries no lado do aplicativo em vez de escrever no lado do banco de dados.

#### Performance

Para o banco de dados, não há nenhuma diferença entre executar queries em stored procedures ou recebidas do client.

Você só conseguirá observar uma mínima diferença de performance entre um e outro devido a variações de ambiente que são muito difíceis de controlar, sendo que ora stored procedures serão ligeiramente mais rápidas e ora a queries enviadas pelo client é que serão ligeiramente mais rápidas.

Onde stored procedures podem ganhar vantagem é no processamento pesado de grande volume de dados, por dois motivos: porque você está mais perto dos dados e não precisa trafegá-los pela rede e porque você pode contar facilmente com o uso do disco usando tabelas físicas e temporárias de modo a não precisar dispor de uma quantidade enorme de memória RAM.

Então, se você não pretende fazer em stored procedures o processamento pesado de grande volume de dados, você pode descartar o fator *performance* da sua tomada de decisão.

Veja, como exemplo, os resultados [desta medição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47889).

#### Complexidade

Cada linguagem introduzida no seu projeto adiciona complexidade. É comum um projeto usar várias linguagens (SQL, C#, ASP e JavaScript, por exemplo), mas a complexidade é algo para lutarmos contra e não para buscarmos gratuitamente. Cada complexidade precisa ter um bom motivo para ser adicionada. Qual é o bom motivo para adicionar a linguagem de stored procedure ao projeto?

Além da complexidade de uma linguagem adicional, há a complexidade de ferramentas adicionais, como de depuração de código. Além de as ferramentas para C# estarem muito mais evoluídas que as ferramentas para Transact-SQL, por exemplo.

#### Estrutura do projeto, dependências, rastreamento, versionamento, deploy...

Todas estas necessidades são mais complexas quando se trata de código de banco de dados do que quando se trata de código padrão do aplicativo. Por sorte, definições de tabelas variam muito menos do que todo o resto (regras de negócio, queries, UI...). De modo que usar código de banco de dados para queries ou regras de negócio aumenta os desafios de gestão do código, de distribuição e de atualização do aplicativo.

#### Escalabilidade

Quando há a necessidade de processar grandes volumes de dados e opta-se por stored procedures, outro problema maior geralmente surge: escalar a solução.

A demanda por muita performance geralmente não tem fim - o volume de dados só cresce e a solução de ontem não atende mais hoje, e servidores de banco de dados são reconhecidos por não permitir escalonamento horizontal. Você coloca no servidor cada vez mais processadores mas descobre que isso custa muito mais caro do que adicionar um novo servidor - acontece que nem todos os servidores de banco de dados suportam paralelismo entre máquinas físicas (ou "cluster ativo"), e os que suportam são soluções caríssimas, muito mais caras do que simplesmente comprar mais um servidor simples ou alocar mais uma máquina na nuvem.

Eu já vi projetos migrando o processamento para o banco de dados (stored procedures) e alguns anos depois migrando de volta para o lado do aplicativo, e os dois movimentos tinham a mesma demanda: mais performance.

#### Portabilidade

A linguagem SQL está bastante padronizada entre os bancos, enquanto a linguagem para escrever stored procedure é bastante específica em cada um deles. De modo que é mais fácil suportar mais de um banco de dados escrevendo apenas SQL em vez de escrever também stored procedures. Por "mais fácil" entenda menos custoso e menos arriscado, uma vez que cada query só precisa ser escrita uma vez enquanto a stored procedure precisa ser reescrita para cada banco de dados.

É claro que este fator só é importante se você deseja suportar mais de um servidor de banco de dados, o que é uma necessidade bastante comum.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta também @Caffé.

Answer (score 2):

### Depende do Sistema

As respostas que já foram apresentadas são muito boas, mas eu vou contribuir com outros aspectos que talvez não existam no seu projeto, mas podem ser relevantes para outros.

> É boa pratica trafegar o texto criado no C# para o banco como no 2º
>   exemplo?  Já ouvi falar que não seria uma boa pratica.

Esse tipo de recomendação de não executar fora do banco pode estar ligada ao fato que tradicionalmente existem profissionais com funções diferentes no desenvolvimento de um sistema. O profissional que trabalha no banco de dados pode escrever consultas mais otimizadas enquanto o desenvolvedor tradicionalmente não é especializado em banco de dados.

Existem aspectos que estão ligados aos requisitos do sistema que podem definir melhor se a escolha é por um lado ou por outro. Por exemplo, se o sistema precisa rodar em vários bancos de dados, é mais custoso ter que escrever as consultas dentro do banco usando a linguagem específica de cada um.

Por outro lado, as `procedures` do banco podem ter facilidades que você não vai encontrar na linguagem que estiver utilizando para o acesso. Se existem um requisito que você precisa garantir a segurança de execução de consultas, talvez seja mais interessante usar as infraestrutura de segurança de objetos do próprio banco de dados.

Hoje em dia, com sistemas rodando em nuvem, não importa muito para o usuário qual é o banco de dados que está sendo utilizado e um projeto pode facilmente ser escrito para rodar em um banco de dados específico e assim se beneficiar de todas as funcionalidades dele. Vejo decisões desse tipo com bancos `NoSQL`, por exemplo.

> Em questões de Manutenibilidade e legibilidade, qual dos exemplos é
>   melhor?

Na parte de manutenção e legibilidade vai depender mais de como você projeta o sistema do que se a consulta está no lado do programa ou do banco.

No seu exemplo você está concatenando o `SQL` tanto de um lado como do outro. Uma alternativa mais legível seria você ter duas consultas, cada uma com a sua finalidade e o programa chamar uma ou outra de acordo com o parâmetro ao invés do parâmetro modificar o `SQL`. Outra forma de fazer esse tipo de mesclagem de forma mais limpa, seria utilizar um mecanismo de template em cima no comando `SQL` da mesma forma que se faz com o `HTML`, por exemplo.

> O exemplo 1 poderia afetar o desempenho do banco, pelo fato de
>   executar os ifs? Qual usar?

Se você for realmente criterioso, o exemplo da consulta escrita no banco, você tem duas execuções. A primeira para interpretar o comando e montar o `SQL` e a segunda que realmente executa o `SQL`. A segunda chamada é interna e o tempo dela é irrelevante. Para o banco, o `SQL` é dinâmico e ele não vai ter a chance de deixar a consulta preparada. Vai ter que rodar a preparação toda vez que o comando for executado.

A consulta sendo enviada do programa, embora represente apenas uma execução, é também dinâmica e o banco não vai ter a chance de deixar ela preparada. É claro que os mecanismos de otimização e *cache* do bancos atuais já fazem um bom trabalho nesse cenário, mas é bom saber o que está acontecendo.

Normalmente os tempos de execução de consultas em banco `SQL` são de uma ordem de magnitude bem maior que os tempos de chamada entre o programa e o banco e dessa forma você precisa se preocupar com a finalidade daquela consulta. Se por exemplo, você precisa fazer uma chamada do programa e com a resposta precisa executar outras chamadas, talvez seja mais interessante que isso tudo esteja em uma `procedure`.

Se por outro lado, você precisa dividir a execução do código para otimizar o resultado, talvez deixar tudo dentro da `procedure` possa te limitar. Dessa forma esse aspecto também deve ser considerado a cada função que você precisa desenhar no sistema.