# CRUD Precisa de Procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Minha dúvida é a seguinte.

Quando criamos uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC que necessita de um CRUD básico.

É indispensável o uso de um banco de dados com procedures.

Ou posso fazer de outra forma ?

Comment: Não é indispensável mesmo que o CRUD não seja básico.

Comment: Procedure não é uma obrigatoriedade para nenhum sistema.

Comment: É que só tenho visto exemplos de CRUD com bancos inteiramente desenvolvidos com procedures, e estou com algumas dúvidas em como devo proceder no meu caso onde meu banco não possui as dita cujas.

Comment: Sinto muito por essa sua experiência ruim :) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15746/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51956/101

Answer (score 1):

Não necessariamente. Você pode optar entre centralizar a lógica de negócio dentro da camada de aplicação (C#, VB.NET) ou dentro do próprio banco de dados. Cada implementação tem as suas vantagens e desvantagens, cabendo ao desenvolvedor escolher o que será mais viável para o projeto.

Comment: Muito interessante,